# Attempting to access iframe contents (different subdomain); tried setting up CORS

Tags: security, iframe, amazon-s3, cross-domain, cors

I am hosting a file at `domain.com`, which contains an iframe whose document is hosted on `s3.domain.com`. I am attempting to access the contents of the iframe, however am receiving the following:

> Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://s3.domain.com.s3.amazonaws.com/file.html from frame with URL http://domain.com/. Domains, protocols and ports must match.

I understand the reason for this. I've found two work arounds.

1. Since I own both documents, I can set the domain property to allow access like so: `document.domain = 'domain.com';`
2. Use CORS to allow access to the document, which is hosted within an S3 bucket

I would prefer to do this, however am having trouble doing so.
My CORS configuration file for the bucket currently looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

This is still, however, resulting in the error. I'm sure I'm missing something, however am not sure what.

Any advice would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

With CORS browsers will usually do a preflight request (`OPTIONS` method). Probably you will have to allow all headers as well to ensure proper preflight request handling:

```
<AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
```

See also [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html#how-do-i-enable-cors).

Comment: no luck. Here are sample response headers from the iframe'd content, if it helps: http://cl.ly/image/3C2n2v3t3G37

Comment: It looks like you're getting no CORS header responses at all. There should be at least an Access-Control-Allow-Origin header. Are you sure it is setup correctly in S3?

Comment: Sorry I don't know why S3 is not emitting CORS headers with your configuration. You could try asking at Amazon.